# How to write this command line?

Tags: command-line, zsh, oh-my-zsh, zshrc

I'm using oh-my-zsh.

I want to make a zsh command `mx google.com`

And have it run the following:

```
dig +short mx $1
```

And then if I run

```
a p
```

where 'p' stands for "previous" (I'm open to other more common conventions here)

I want it to run (hypothetical if previous line outputs 3 IPs):

```
dig + short a ip1
dig + short a ip2
dig + short a ip3
```

for each result returned in the previous command.

The commands I want to support with the above convention are `a`, `txt`, `mx`, `cname`

This was currently all I had:

```
alias a='f() { dig +short a $1 };f'
```

but I am not sure how to combine the two.

Comment: Don't tag your question with bash if you aren't using bash.

Comment: Using an alias to define a function is rather novel.  But you really shouldn't use aliases at all!  Use functions.

Comment: @WilliamPursell ha, ok. I see how that is just a layer of indirection that's not needed.

Comment: Having a command depend on the output previous commands requires that all the output of every command be stored somewhere.  The shell does not store that data.(bash, that is, I don't know much about zsh and maybe it does actually store everything!)   However, assuming you're using `tmux` (or some other similar tool), you could scrape the pane to get that data.